# how to display parent record and children from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have three tables, 1 parent with 2 child table 1-to-many relationships.
table 1: People
table 2: Phone numbers (any number of records)
table 3: email adresses (any number of records)

I would like a report looking like this:
Person1:
First_Name-------Last_Name
phone1:------12345----Home
phone2:------54321----work
mail1:-------first@mail.com----work
mail2:-------first@mail.com----work
mail3:-------first@mail.com----work

Person2:
-------First_Name-------Last_Name
phone1:------12345----Home
phone2:------54321----work
mail1:-------first@mail.com----work
mail2:-------first@mail.com----work
mail3:-------first@mail.com----work

I would very much like to do this using reporting services.

Edit: I know how to link all tables with left joins, I don't have a concept as how to get this done.

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question

Comment: It looks like you don't know much about SSRS. Try to learn about it, try it yourself and If you get stuck ask us specifically what the problem is. This [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859.aspx) might help you.

Comment: See question. I really have no clue as where to get started.

Comment: Follow this tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167305.aspx) to get started

Comment: Ah. Thats helpful(!). I know how to group data in SRSS with totals. Would you know about a way to get your data in the top group in rows and not in columns? That would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a sort of summary of how you need to approach it.  I can't give you a step-by-step because it would be impossibly long, but this should get you started.  (Also note that I'm doing this from memory):

1. You will need three datasets, one each for people, phone numbers, and email addresses.  I am going to assume that the phone numbers and email addresses have some kind of ID field in common, some way to tie people to phones and to email addresses.  You will need that field in your datasets.

   You don't need to do any joins in your SQL:  the linking between the three datasets will be done within the report.
2. Put a Matrix on your report. Have it draw from the People dataset.  Put the first and last name in the detail row of the Matrix.
3. Add a new detail row to your Matrix, under your first and last name.
4. Merge the cells in your new detail row so that you have one very wide cell.
5. Embed (drag and drop) a new Matrix in the single wide cell in your new detail row.
6. Link your matrix to the Phones dataset.  Set up a record filter in the matrix to limit the records to those that match the ID field in the parent matrix.
7. Set up the Phones as you want in the embedded child Matrix.
8. Repeat steps 3-7 with the Email Addresses dataset.

You don't actually need to do any grouping (unless you want to include subtotals of some kind), because you're not actually grouping anything:  you're just displaying a list with embedded sub-lists.

Comment: Thanks so much. I do get an error: "Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope" testing a second, embedded matrix. Would you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: A report item usually refers to a display item on the report.  Does it say what report item it's complaining about?  What is the expression that it's trying to display?